# R lm interaction terms with categorical and squared continuous variables

Tags: r, interaction, lm

I am trying to get an lm fit for my data. The problem I am having is that I want to fit a linear model(1st order polynomial) when the factor is "true" and a second order polynomial when the factor is "false". How can I get that done using only one lm.

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b=factor(c("true","false","true","false","true","false","true","false","true","false"))
c=c(10,8,20,15,30,21,40,25,50,31)
DumbData<-data.frame(cbind(a,c))
DumbData<-cbind(DumbData,b=b)
```

I have tried

```
Lm2<-lm(c~a + b + b*I(a^2), data=DumbData)
summary(Lm2)
```

that results in:

```
summary(Lm2)
Call:
lm(formula = c ~ a + b + b * I(a^2), data = DumbData)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.74483    1.12047  -0.665 0.535640    
a             4.44433    0.39619  11.218 9.83e-05 ***
btrue         6.78670    0.78299   8.668 0.000338 ***
I(a^2)       -0.13457    0.03324  -4.049 0.009840 ** 
btrue:I(a^2)  0.18719    0.01620  11.558 8.51e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.7537 on 5 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9982, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9967 
F-statistic:   688 on 4 and 5 DF,  p-value: 4.896e-07
```

here I have I(a^2) for both fits and i want 1 1st order and another with second order polynomials.
 If one tries with:

```
 Lm2<-lm(c~a + b + I(b*I(a^2)), data=DumbData)
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(b, I(a^2)) : * not meaningful for factors
```

How can I get the proper interaction terms here???

Thanks Andrie, there are still some things I am missing here. In this example the variable b is a logic one, if is a factor of two levels does not work, I guess I have to convert the factor variable in a logic one. The other thing I am missing is the not in the condition, I(!b*a^2) without the ! I get:

```
    Call: lm(formula = c ~ a + I(b * a^2), data = dat) 
Coefficients: Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) 
(Intercept) 7.2692 1.8425 3.945 0.005565 ** 
a           2.3222 0.3258 7.128 0.000189 *** 
I(b * a^2)  0.3005 0.0355 8.465 6.34e-05 ***
```

I can not relate the formulas with and without the ! condition, which is a bit strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the following lines:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  b=c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE),
  c=c(10,8,20,15,30,21,40,25,50,31)
)

fit <- lm(c ~ a + I(!b * a^2), dat)
summary(fit)
```

This results in:

```
Call:
lm(formula = c ~ a + I(!b * a^2), data = dat)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
 -4.60  -2.65   0.50   2.65   4.40 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      10.5000     2.6950   3.896 0.005928 ** 
a                 3.9000     0.4209   9.266 3.53e-05 ***
I(!b * a^2)TRUE -13.9000     2.4178  -5.749 0.000699 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 3.764 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9367, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9186 
F-statistic: 51.75 on 2 and 7 DF,  p-value: 6.398e-05
```

Note:

- I made use of the logical values `TRUE` and `FALSE`.
- These will coerce to 1 and 0, respectively.
- I used the negation `!b` inside the formula.

Comment: Thanks Andrie, there are still somethings I am missing here. In this example the variable b is a logic one, if is a factor of two levels does not work, I guess I have to convert the factor variable in a logic one. The other thing I am missing is the not in the condition, I(!b*a^2) without the ! I get: Call:
lm(formula = c ~ a + I(b * a^2), data = dat)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   7.2692     1.8425   3.945 0.005565 ** 
a             2.3222     0.3258   7.128 0.000189 ***
I(b * a^2)    0.3005     0.0355   8.465 6.34e-05 ***

Answer (score 1):

Ummm ...

```
Lm2<-lm(c~a + b + b*I(a^2), data=DumbData)
```

You say that "The problem I am having is that I want to fit a linear model(1st order polynomial) when the factor is "true" and a second order polynomial when the factor is "false". How can I get that done using only one lm. "

From that I infer that you don't want b to be directly in the model? In addition, a^2 should be included only if b is false.

So that would be...

```
lm(c~ a + I((!b) * a^2))
```

If b is true (that is, !b equals FALSE) then a^2 is multiplied by zero (FALSE) and omitted from the equation.

The only problem is that you have defined b as factor instead of `logical`. That can be cured.

```
# b=factor(c("true","false","true","false","true","false","true","false","true","false"))
# could use TRUE and FALSE instead of "ture" and "false"
# alternatively, after defining b as above, do
# b <- b=="true" -- that would convert b to logical (i.e boolean TRUE and FALSe values)
```

Ok to be exact, you defined b as "character" but it was converted to "factor" when adding it to the data frame ("DumbData")

Another minor point about the way you defined the data frame.

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b=factor(c("true","false","true","false","true","false","true","false","true","false"))
c=c(10,8,20,15,30,21,40,25,50,31)
DumbData<-data.frame(cbind(a,c))
DumbData<-cbind(DumbData,b=b)
```

Here, cbind is unnecessary. You coud have it all on one line:

```
Dumbdata<- data.frame(a,b,c)
# shorter and cleaner!!
```

In addition, to convert b to `logical` use:

```
Dumbdata<- data.frame(a,b=b=="true",c)
```

Note. You need to say b=b=="true", it seems redundant but the LHS (b) gives the name of the variable in data frame whereas the RHS (b=="true") is an expression that evaluates to a "logical" (boolean) value.